# NodeJS receive data from a form, edit and send again

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, oauth-2.0

Basically I receive the values from a form with the function event:

```
 var formData="";
 req.on('data', function (chunk){
     formData += chunk;
 });
```

And I send those values again in another http.request:

```
 req.on('end', function (){          
  var options = { port: conf.port, path: req.path, 
                  host: conf.host, method: req.method , headers: req.headers};
  authReq = http.request(options, 
            function (response){...});

  authReq.write(formData);
  authReq.end();
});
```

What I want is to add more data to the form receive from the previously form, like for example something like this:

```
var formData="client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXX&";
req.on('data', function (chunk){
    formData += chunk;
});
```

But this is not working, after made the authReq.write(formData); looks like the data send is empty or wrong....  any suggestion ?

Comment: You'll get better feedback if you a) indent the code properly, nobody wants to scroll horizontally; and b) you reduce your problem to a minimal version, so that we don't have to go through unrelated and application-specific code

Comment: The problem is that I can not concat another string to fromData string which has the data from the form...

Answer (score 0):

In the second request, the variable `formData` filled in the first request, will be empty. 
You might need to use a session. (http://expressjs-book.com/forums/topic/express-js-sessions-a-detailed-tutorial/)

Also, from the looks of your code snippets, I suggest you look into http://passportjs.org/ for authentication :)

Comment: I am using OAuth2, what I need is to add my client_secret and client_id to the request in the server side, before send the request to the oauth server from nodejs

Comment: The problem was the headers in the request, instead of usinng the headers that came by default y sus rewrite then with a simple value.

var options = { port: conf.port, path: req.path, host: conf.host, method: req.method , headers: {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}  };

:)